# Java Help (Waituntil?)

Tags: java, client, minecraft, runtimemodification

I want to create a java function, like a wait until this has passed in seconds, then they may preform the action.. Here is what I have:

```
    if(Minecraft.getMinecraft().gameSettings.keyBindJump.pressed)
        hasTimePassedS(2);
        Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.motionY = + 8;


    private boolean hasTimePassedS(int i) {
    long t0 = 0,t1 = 1;
     do{
     }
     while (t1-t0<1000);
    return false;
```

Note: These are two different samples, no correct { } format is used/regarded.

I want there to be a two second delay after the top code is activated before you can press it again.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `Thread.sleep(2000);` **or** use a `Timer`.

Comment: I don't want the program to freeze?

Comment: I want it to basically stop that specific function

Comment: For two seconds, so when they press it again before the delay, it does nothing

Comment: How do I create a timer?

Answer (score 0):

You could create (and `start`) a [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). Also, I'm pretty sure you meant `+= 8` (not `= +8`) Something like,

```
if (Minecraft.getMinecraft().gameSettings.keyBindJump.pressed) {
  Timer t = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.motionY += 8;
    }
  });
  t.start();
}
```

Comment: I mean = +,
The timer does not exactly work, what imports would you import, just to make sure?

Comment: @Hobo `javax.swing.Timer` (I linked to the Javadoc). Also, `+8` is just `8`.

Comment: Still does not work, will get back with you tomorrow going to bed.

Comment: What ends up happening is when the function is not pressed, it preforms the else function

Comment: I have an else function after this, which makes the player float (- .04) in their y axis..

Comment: I will list the full source code when I get home, hopefully you can help